# What is "overhead"?

Tags: overhead

What is overhead? Are there multiple types of overhead, or only one? What are some examples?

Comment: Google Define Overhead: http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&defl=en&q=define:overhead&sa=X&ei=x1C7TOyFOIP-8Ab18pmHDw&ved=0CBIQkAE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The business meaning of [overhead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overhead_%28business%29) cost explains it best. From Wikipedia:

> The term overhead is usually used to
>   group expenses that are necessary to
>   the continued functioning of the
>   business, but cannot be immediately
>   associated with the products/services
>   being offered[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overhead_%28business%29) (e.g. do not directly
>   generate profits).

Overhead is a "cost" you will incur to be able to perform an operation; you need to "invest" some resource to perform the operation in question.

Answer (score 3):

Overhead is any usage of a particular resource that's a side-effect of what you're actually trying to achieve.  e.g. Struct padding is a form of memory overhead.  Pushing and popping arguments on the stack is a form of processing overhead.  Packet headers are a form of bandwidth overhead.  Think of a resource, it can have an overhead associated with it.

Comment: i wouldn't say "undesired" but more like "side-effect".

Comment: @tenfour: Yes, that's much better.  I've worked that into my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of size overhead for structs and classes:

```
struct first {
    char letter1;
    int number;
    char letter2;
};

struct second {
    int number;
    char letter1;
    char letter2;
};

int main ()
{
    cout << "Size of first: " << sizeof(first) << endl;
    cout << "Size of second: " << sizeof(second) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
Size of first: 12
Size of second: 8
```

The compiler must build a struct to be word-aligned. In the first struct, the surrounding char's (one byte each) cause the compiler to "push" the int down so that it can be accessed as a full word (four bytes). The second struct doesn't require nearly as much pushing.

Moral of the story: place similar-size data members next to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of time overhead, related to better use of locality to exploit the cache:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 1024

double A[SIZE][SIZE], B[SIZE][SIZE], C[SIZE][SIZE];

int main ()
{
    int i, j, k;

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < SIZE; k++) {
                C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Running this on my machine takes this much time:

```
real    0m35.137s
user    0m34.996s
sys     0m0.067s
```

Now I'll swap the j and k loop iterations:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 1024

double A[SIZE][SIZE], B[SIZE][SIZE], C[SIZE][SIZE];

int main ()
{
    int i, j, k;

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (k = 0; k < SIZE; k++) {            // this is the only change
            for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
                C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
            }
        }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

The runtime for this is:

```
real    0m5.489s
user    0m5.436s
sys     0m0.040s
```

It's much faster because the loop iterations are more in-line with the order of the array indices. Thus, the data is more likely to be accessed consecutively, and thus more likely to be available in cache.